# Is it possible to go deeper than nearest superclass (i.e. super.super)?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Assume that I want to skip one level in call `super.viewDidLoad()`, for example. So I wish to be able to do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

or

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [[super super] viewDidLoad];
}
```

This code will not compile. Is this possible by some other solution?

Comment: why? this is probably a bad idea

Comment: @Lu_ I used `viewDidLoad` only like well known example; thought my interest in this question is pretty theoretical

Comment: It's possible, using the runtime to figure out both the super's superclass and that class's implementation of the method.  You'd then invoke it directly.  It's a really, really, really (times a billion) bad idea.

Comment: Why [super super] should also implements that method? What if it's only the father that implements it and not the grandfather (which could be resolved with a `respondsToSelector()`, I admit). Also, if you want to really call [[super super] method] and bypass the custom implementation of the father, then, your architecture may not be the good one. Also why [super method] call itself [super method] for some important stuff, but again, if you want to by pass the father call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expository purposes only, the following code does as requested.  It only fails to crash when compiled without ARC, which means it has a bug in it.  It does no error checking.

**Never use this code unless you are playing around and trying to learn.**

```
@import Foundation;
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@interface M : NSObject

- (void)print;

@end

@implementation M

- (void)print { NSLog(@"M"); }

@end

@interface N : M
@end

@implementation N

- (void)print { NSLog(@"N"); }

@end

@interface O : N
@end

@implementation O

- (void)print {
    Class mysupersuper = [[self superclass] superclass];
    Method supersuperMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(mysupersuper, _cmd);

    method_invoke(self, supersuperMethod);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    O *o = O.new;

    [o print];

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using the command: `clang -framework Foundation -fno-objc-arc  -fmodules test.m`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do in Swift.  Suppose you have classes A and B:

```
class A
{
     func fun() { print("called fun() in A") }
}

class B : A
{
    override func fun() { print("called fun() in B") }
}
```

You can't modify their definitions, but want to call fun() from A in a class C derived from B.  You could do that as follows:

```
extension B
{
    func funInA()
    {
        super.fun()
    }
}

class C : B
{
    override func fun() { funInA() }
}
```

I think you can pull off something like this in Objective-C using categories.